# Pass POST data into a PHP function

Tags: php, function, post

I want to upload an image file with PHP. How can I pass POST data to a PHP function in another file, which will be executed when the submit button is clicked...

here is the form:

```
 <!-- edit users profile picture -->
<form method="post" action="edit.php" name="user_edit_profile_picture">
    <input type="file" name="profil_slika" id="profil_slika">
    <input type="submit" name="user_edit_submit_profile_picture">

    <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");
        $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '".$_SESSION['user_name']."'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
            echo $row['user_name'];
            if($row['image'] == ""){
                echo "<img width='100' height='100' src='profile_pictures/default_user.png' alt='Default Profile Pic'>";
            } else {
                echo "<img width='100' height='100' src='profile_pictures/".$row['image']."' alt='Profile Pic'>";
            }
            echo "<br>";
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

and this is another PHP file with function:

```
elseif(isset($_POST["user_edit_submit_profile_picture"])) {
                $this->editUserPicture($_POST['profil_slika']);
            }
```

and function body:

```
public function editUserPicture($profilimage){

        $slika = $_FILES[$profilimage]['tmp_name'];
echo $slika;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$profilimage]['tmp_name'],"profile_pictures/".$_FILES[$profilimage]['name']);

}
```

Currently I am getting this error message when I click on submit:

Notice: Undefined index: image.jpg in C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\classes\Login.php on line 55

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```php
$this->editUserPicture($_POST['profil_slika']);
```

To this:

```php
$this->editUserPicture('profil_slika');
```

And also add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the attributes of the HTML `<form>`.

The reason is that `profil_slika` will *not* be passed to the `$_POST` array. It will be in the `$_FILES` array, with key `profil_slika`. In other words, the key you need to use for the `$_FILES` array *is* the `name` of the HTML `input`, you don't need to use `$_POST` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your form tag with this and try:

```
<form method="post" action="edit.php" name="user_edit_profile_picture" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Function:

```
elseif(isset($_POST["user_edit_submit_profile_picture"])) {
    $this->editUserPicture('profil_slika');
}
```

Function body:

```
public function editUserPicture($profilimage){
        $slika = $_FILES[$profilimage]['tmp_name'];
        echo $slika;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$profilimage]['tmp_name'],"profile_pictures/".$_FILES[$profilimage]['name']);

}
```

Comment: now I get another error: Notice: Undefined index: profil_slika in C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\classes\Login.php on line ...

Comment: Also please change following code: elseif(isset($_POST["user_edit_submit_profile_picture"])) {
                $this->editUserPicture($_FILES['profil_slika']);
            }

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\classes\Login.php on line 562
Array
Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\classes\Login.php on line 563

Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\classes\Login.php on line 565

Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\classes\Login.php on line 565

Comment: Change one more time: elseif(isset($_POST["user_edit_submit_profile_picture"])) {
           $this->editUserPicture($_FILES['profil_slika']['name']);
    }